# Does the asymptotic formula for Partitions into parts <c exist?

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, partitions

A partition of $n$ is a weakly decreasing tuple of numbers $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,....\lambda_k)$ whose sum is $n.$  A natural problem studied is counting partitions whose summands $\lambda_i$ all like in a set $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ and we denote this number $p_S(n)$.

If $S$ is ``dense" enough, one can usually calculate an asymptotic formula that looks like $$p_S(n) = Kn^\beta\exp\left(c\sqrt{n}\right)\left(1+ \frac{c_1}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{c_2}{n}+\frac{c_3}{n^\frac{3}{2}} \dots \right).$$

My question is when $S=\mathbb{N}\setminus [0,1,2,\dots c]$ does such a formula already exist in the literature and where can I find it?

Comment: The tuple notation generally implies an ordering, whereas in partition counting one generally considers $1+2$ and $2+1$ to be the same partition of 3. Partitions into parts not exceeding $c$ is the same as partitions into at most $c$ parts, and I think asymptotically that's $Cn^{c-1}$, which is negligible compared to the full number of partitions.

Comment: I forgot the decreasing part of the definition and its parts greater than c rather than less than c.  My fault and I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts greater than $c$ is complementary to parts smaller than $c.$ (as pointed out in the comments, parts greater than $c$ is the same as "at least $c$ parts") for the latter, there is a theorem of Szekeres from 1951, see the [math review.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/szekeres.pdf) (of. Course this doesn't answer the question,  but will leave answer up for the seekers reference) 2 3rd

Comment: Link is broken and similar posted in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347035/number-of-positive-integer-solutions-with-a-lower-bound?noredirect=1&lq=1.