# Number of positive integer solutions with a lower bound

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

If $0\leq\gamma<\alpha<1$ and $t=\lceil n^\gamma\rceil$ hold then how many positive solutions to the linear diophantine equation

$$x_1+\dots+x_t=\lceil n^\alpha\rceil$$

have the property

$$n^\beta\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\dots\leq x_t\leq\lceil n^\alpha\rceil$$ when $0\leq\beta<\alpha-\gamma$?

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136726/does-the-asymptotic-formula-for-partitions-into-parts-c-exist?rq=1

Comment: Is $\ell$ fixed?

Comment: You mean $t$? $t$ can vary but even for fixed I am not sure of the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting $\lceil n^\beta\rceil-1$ from every $x_i$ translates the problem to the [number of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) of $\lceil n^\alpha\rceil - t(\lceil n^\beta\rceil-1)$ into $t$ parts:
$$p_t(\lceil n^\alpha\rceil - t(\lceil n^\beta\rceil-1)).$$

Comment: This is the case for fixed $t$...

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: It is fixed as OP states that $t=\lceil n^\gamma\rceil$ for some $\gamma$. But even if it's variable, then summation over suitable $t$ will give the answer.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that

Comment: @VS.: Please see the provided Wikipedia link for notation and asymptotic.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Is there expressions and asymptotics for $p_t$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Asymptotics with $A=\{1,2,\dots,t\}$.